# How store the Post ID of a new WordPress document in a custom field in that document

Tags: wordpress, hook, action

I have what is in essence a very simple problem but alas I'm a newbie in WP development.
Whenever a post is created I want to save the POST ID of that new post in a custom field called meta_post_id.

Why? Well later in Caldera Forms I want to use this field to make sure Caldera updates the existing post instead of creating a new one and all works except that I can't find a way to get the POST ID the first time into the meta_post_id field. If I manually put it in then the rest works.

Suggestions?
A bit of sample code would be great!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Asking for code or general coding guidance is against the guidelines. After you make a good attempt at solving this yourself and if you still have problems, you can edit your question with details of the specific problem, what you have tried & your relevant code in a minimal,reproducible example, so we are able to help.

Comment: Hi Jan, can you please rephrase your question to "How can I add meta data to a newly created post?" I would delete your second and third paragraphs and remove the text "the POST ID of that new post in" from the first paragraph. Then you should be good. What you're specifically doing and why is not relevant to getting the answer your need and it got the question flagged as low quality. Unless that of course you are asking a Caldera Forms specific question. Then you can rephrase for that specific root problem.

Comment: @PhilF Those changes would actually do more harm than good. The first sentence is also against guidelines so all you are leaving is a one-liner that says "*I want this*" which is absolutely goes against everything SO is about. The required result might be clearer but it would actually make the question even worse than the current one! We still need to see *evidence of research* and a *good attempt at doing it themselves* with a *minimal & reproducible example* of their code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use a WordPress hook on a new post...

```php
add_action('wp_insert_post', function ($post_id, $post, $update) {
    if (!in_array($post->post_type, ['revision']) && !in_array($post->post_status, ['auto-draft']) && $update) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_post_id', $post_id);
    }
}, 10, 3);
```

It's actually a bit trickier than this because WordPress considers any update to a post a new post. It's because it saves a revision (a new post with a post type of revision) in the background, thus we need filter out some scenarios to get exactly what you want. So I would need a little more detail to optimize this much more. Nevertheless, this should be sufficient for what you're trying to do. The only downside is that is probably going to run a few more times than necessary, but it's not going to affect what you're trying to do.

I left things as in_array checks, so you can easily filter out false positives later, if necessary. For example, you may also want to filter out post statuses of 'draft' as well.

Comment: *”I'm sure most people are going to comment on the fact there is most likely a better way to solve your problem”*...no, it’s more likely that fact that it against Stack Overflow guidelines to answer low quality questions see “**Answer well-asked questions**” in [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For future reference, it’s better to use the comments to guide the user into editing their question to make it a good question that meets the guidelines :)